# How to install .NET Core SDK 2.1.401 after having installed version 2.1.500?

Tags: .net-core

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I updated my .NET Core installation to the latest version `2.1.500` a few days ago.

Shortly after, I wanted to play with the source code for MS Build, so I cloned the [MS Build git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild) and ran their `build.cmd` file [as instructed](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild#building-msbuild-with-visual-studio-2017).

But [it kept failing](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3937) telling me it wasn't able to download the per-requisite .NET Core version `2.1.401`.

```
C:\Source\Of\MSBuild> build.cmd

dotnet-install: Downloading link: 
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.401/dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-win-x64.zip

dotnet-install: Cannot download: 
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.401/dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-win-x64.zip

dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: 
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.401/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.401.zip

Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): 
"Failed to download 
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.401/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.401.zip."

yada yada yada yada...
```

So I downloaded the zip file `https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.401/dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-win-x64.zip` manually, and unzipped it to find a `dotnet.exe` in it.

First thinking that it was a set-up file, I double-clicked it. It appeared and disappeared quickly.

Then, after a few failed attempts, I suspected it *was indeed the SDK itself* and wasn't an install-able set-up. So, I checked the folders in the unzipped file and they matched *exactly* the folders in my `C:\Program Files\dotnet` folder (see the picture at the bottom of this question).

So, now, I don't know how to have *this* version of .NET Core that I just downloaded (`v 2.1.401`) co-exist with the latest version `2.1.500.` I do see that the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\` folder has several versions exist side by side:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk>dir /b
1.0.0
1.0.0-preview2-003131
2.1.500
NuGetFallbackFolder
```

So, should I just go ahead and mess around with my folders manually? That is, should I just copy and paste the folders I downloaded and merge them with what I have? See below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the two folders needn't have to be merged. One must download the .NET Core installer instead.

Two issues need to be addressed in answering this question.

1. I had downloaded the binaries in a zip file and not an installer. I was led to install the binaries because the URL I saw on the console when I ran the build script pointed to the binaries and not to the installer.

   .NET Core comes in two kinds of packages:

   a. MSI installers; and

   b. Zip files containing the binaries. These are useful when you want to hold a private copy of .NET core in your application. Just like NPM packages have private installations in contrast to public/global ones. Just like you hold private assemblies (`CopyLocal = True`) of the .NET framework within your application in contrast with references them from the GAC or the Reference Assemblies folder.

   Look at [this SDK download page on the Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks). It lists both, the binaries and the installers for each version of the SDK and the runtime.
2. A [Powershell script in the MS Build build process](https://github.com/Sathyaish/msbuild/blob/master/build/build.ps1#L192) downloads the zip file containing only the binaries and it holds this version of the .NET Core privately. The version it is looking for is mentioned in the [`DotNetCliVersion` property in the `Version.props` file](https://github.com/Sathyaish/msbuild/blob/master/build/Versions.props#L39).

[**From build1.ps**](https://github.com/Sathyaish/msbuild/blob/master/build/build.ps1#L192)

```
function Build {
  if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DotNetCoreSdkDir) -and 
                               (Test-Path -Path $DotNetCoreSdkDir)) {
    $env:DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR = $DotNetCoreSdkDir
  }
  else {
    InstallDotNetCli
  }

  $env:DOTNET_HOST_PATH = Join-Path $env:DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR "dotnet.exe"

  ...
```